# Authenticating against ExpressionEngine

Tags: login, authentication

I'm working on the new CMS implementation project.
We have ~4000 users in ExpressionEngine v 1.6.3 CMS.

The project requirement is, to let current EE members login to new CMS based on their encrypted credentials in EE.

Is the any way I can run an external php script utilizing Authentication Function from EE core
$this->EE->auth->authenticate_username($username, $password)?

Any help will be appreciated.

Pawel

Comment: Can you clarify a couple details: is the new CMS in EE 2?

Comment: $this->EE->auth->authenticate_username($username, $password) doesn't seems to be working with version 1.6.3

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: So.. was this ever figured out?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest building a simple API module within the EE installation.

You've found the Auth library which should do exactly what you need, it's just a matter of exposing it, because there really isn't an easy way to take EE's authentication scheme out of EE.

So once you create a module, it'd simply be a matter of setting up an action ID within the module and having it accept the username and password via POST. Then you can have it return in whatever format you like (JSON, XML, etc).

Your new CMS can then use CURL to connect to the API you've created.